# Regular expression to replace spaces between numbers with a comma

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have a huge list of the following in a large file that contains information about every country in the world.

They are arrays of temperature data, sometimes the spaces vary in length.

```
[23.5  26.3  29.3  31.9  32.8  31.2  28.8  27.8  28.4  29  26.6  23.7]
```

I'm attempting to use sublime to write a regular expression but I cannot get my head around them.

So far the closest thing I've got is:

```
( \S+)\(.+ )
```

How would one write a regular expression replacing the line to look like this:

```
[23.8,25.5,27.2,28.3,29.3,29.5,28.7,28.1,28.2,28.9,27.2,24.4]
```

Any help would be great thanks.

**Edit
I'm using sublime text.

Comment: Whats wrong with `\s`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this: `(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d|\-)`, using find and replace all in sublime text.

`(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind, it checks if the previous symbol is a digit, without actually matching it.

`(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead, same thing - checks if the following symbol is a digit, without actually matching it.

Just FYI, lookbehinds aren't supported in javascript, but that doesn't matter in this case.

https://regex101.com/r/qX1qF5/7 for easier fiddling with it.

Comment: I was going to post this, add some explanation for people who don't understand what it is doing.

Comment: The above comment also needs to include negatives for negative temperatures. (I managed to tweak it too work.)

Comment: Updated with some explanation, yes, the look ahead can look like this: `(?=\d|\-)` to include matching negatives

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
(\d)\s+(\d)
```

And the in the replace:

```
$1,$2
```

[image: RegEx Answer]

How it works:

1. `(\d)` - Find a digit and capture it
2. `\s+` - that has one or more spaces after it.
3. `(\d)` - and is followed by another digit and capture it.

Doing a "Replace All" with those settings turns this:

```
[23.5  26.3  29.3  31.9  32.8  31.2  28.8  27.8  28.4  29  26.6  23.7]
```

Into:

```
[23.5,26.3,29.3,31.9,32.8,31.2,28.8,27.8,28.4,29,26.6,23.7]
```

Note that if there are any other places in your data file that have a digits followed by some number of white space characters followed by another digit that will as be affected. If that happens there are other ways to refine this but it would require seeing samples of the rest of the data. And, at some point, if there is too much going on, trying to solve it with a single RegEx may be impossible without effecting other data.

Comment: The json is formatted in a away that I'd need spaces. Country names etc etc.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns if country names are in the data, please amend your example data to show that

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns - No problem. I updated the answer to only find spaces between numbers. (Indecently, it wasn't clear from your question that there was anything other than the numbers array. Your best bet with this type of question is including a little more of the data if there are different structures.)

Comment: Yeah how would I implement this? It removed a big portion of the data.

Comment: Your new answer will also replace the digits.

Comment: That was my bad. I didn't test it after getting the new info about the country names. What needs to be done is to capture the digits and put them back in during the replace. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for you're great help man, but unfortunately the guy below found the answer! Once again thanks :-)